# Tablayout not sticking

Tags: android, toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I am using toolbar with tablayout. Below is my main xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager_booking_mng"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

In this current code toolbar is not scrolling. when I scroll the list.

But when I set  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" in Tablayout tag then both the tablaout and toolbar are scrolling and both are getting outside of the screen.

I want only toolbar to scroll and tablayout should get pinned at top(just like whatsapp).

Answer (score 0):

Give scroll flag for the Tablayout as

app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"

Hope this wil work.